# Cache size estimation on your system?

Tags: c, performance, caching, cpu-cache

I got this program from this link (https://gist.github.com/jiewmeng/3787223).I have been searching the web with the idea of gaining a better understanding of processor caches (L1 and L2).I want to be able to write a program that would enable me to guess the size of L1 and L2 cache on my new Laptop.(just for learning purpose.I know I could check the spec.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define KB 1024
#define MB 1024 * 1024

int main() {
    unsigned int steps = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
    static int arr[4 * 1024 * 1024];
    int lengthMod;
    unsigned int i;
    double timeTaken;
    clock_t start;
    int sizes[] = {
        1 * KB, 4 * KB, 8 * KB, 16 * KB, 32 * KB, 64 * KB, 128 * KB, 256 * KB,
        512 * KB, 1 * MB, 1.5 * MB, 2 * MB, 2.5 * MB, 3 * MB, 3.5 * MB, 4 * MB
    };
    int results[sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(int)];
    int s;

    /*for each size to test for ... */
    for (s = 0; s < sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(int); s++)
    {
            lengthMod = sizes[s] - 1;
            start = clock();
            for (i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                arr[(i * 16) & lengthMod] *= 10;
                arr[(i * 16) & lengthMod] /= 10;
            }

            timeTaken = (double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("%d, %.8f \n", sizes[s] / 1024, timeTaken);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program in my machine is as follows.How do I interpret the numbers? What does this program tell me.?

```
1, 1.07000000 
4, 1.04000000 
8, 1.06000000 
16, 1.13000000 
32, 1.14000000 
64, 1.17000000 
128, 1.20000000 
256, 1.21000000 
512, 1.19000000 
1024, 1.23000000 
1536, 1.23000000 
2048, 1.46000000 
2560, 1.21000000 
3072, 1.45000000 
3584, 1.47000000 
4096, 1.94000000
```

Comment: Not a cache expert, but it appears to process chunks of data of increasing size while keeping time. Therefore, you 'should' be able to make some guesses as to how large your cache is by seeing the fluctuations in the timing. I suggest you plot those in excel as it will give you a better picture.

Comment: It tells me that something weird is going on.  It should not take > 1 second to process 1024 iterations of that loop!

Comment: You have several bugs in your code, mainly the fact you keep accessing the same address instead of sweeping over your data set. See my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **you need direct access to memory**

   I am not meaning **DMA** transfer by this. Memory must be accessed by **CPU** of course (otherwise you are not measuring **CACHE**s) but as directly as it can be ... so measurements will probably not be very accurate on **Windows/Linux** because services and other processes can mess with caches during runtime. Measure many times and average for better results (or use the fastest time or filter it together). For best accuracy use **DOS** and **asm** for example

   ```
   rep + movsb,movsw,movsd 
   rep + stosb,stosw,stosd
   ```

   **so you measure the memory transfer and not something else like in your code !!!**
2. **measure the raw transfer times and plot a graph**

   - `x` axis is transfer block size
   - `y` axis is transfer speed

   [image: graph]

   zones with the same transfer rate are consistent with appropriate **CACHE** layer

**[Edit1]** could not find my old source code for this so I busted something right now in **C++** for **windows**:

**Time measurement:**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double performance_Tms=-1.0,    // perioda citaca [ms]
       performance_tms= 0.0;    // zmerany cas [ms]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tbeg()
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    if (performance_Tms<=0.0) { QueryPerformanceFrequency(&i); performance_Tms=1000.0/double(i.QuadPart); }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); performance_tms=double(i.QuadPart);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double tend()
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); performance_tms=double(i.QuadPart)-performance_tms; performance_tms*=performance_Tms;
    return performance_tms;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Benchmark (32bit app):**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD sizes[]=                  // used transfer block sizes
    {
      1<<10,  2<<10,  3<<10,  4<<10,  5<<10,  6<<10,  7<<10,  8<<10,  9<<10,
     10<<10, 11<<10, 12<<10, 13<<10, 14<<10, 15<<10, 16<<10, 17<<10, 18<<10,
     19<<10, 20<<10, 21<<10, 22<<10, 23<<10, 24<<10, 25<<10, 26<<10, 27<<10,
     28<<10, 29<<10, 30<<10, 31<<10, 32<<10, 48<<10, 64<<10, 80<<10, 96<<10,
    112<<10,128<<10,192<<10,256<<10,320<<10,384<<10,448<<10,512<<10,  1<<20,
      2<<20,  3<<20,  4<<20,  5<<20,  6<<20,  7<<20,  8<<20,  9<<20, 10<<20,
     11<<20, 12<<20, 13<<20, 14<<20, 15<<20, 16<<20, 17<<20, 18<<20, 19<<20,
     20<<20, 21<<20, 22<<20, 23<<20, 24<<20, 25<<20, 26<<20, 27<<20, 28<<20,
     29<<20, 30<<20, 31<<20, 32<<20,
    };
const int N=sizeof(sizes)>>2;   // number of used sizes
double pmovsd[N];               // measured transfer rate rep MOVSD [MB/sec]
double pstosd[N];               // measured transfer rate rep STOSD [MB/sec]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void measure()
    {
    int i;
    BYTE *dat;                              // pointer to used memory
    DWORD adr,siz,num;                      // local variables for asm
    double t,t0;
    HANDLE hnd;                             // process handle

    // enable priority change (huge difference)
    #define measure_priority

    // enable critical sections (no difference)
//  #define measure_lock

    for (i=0;i<N;i++) pmovsd[i]=0.0;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) pstosd[i]=0.0;
    dat=new BYTE[sizes[N-1]+4];             // last DWORD +4 Bytes (should be 3 but i like 4 more)
    if (dat==NULL) return;
    #ifdef measure_priority
    hnd=GetCurrentProcess(); if (hnd!=NULL) { SetPriorityClass(hnd,REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS); CloseHandle(hnd); }
    Sleep(200);                             // wait to change take effect
    #endif
    #ifdef measure_lock
    CRITICAL_SECTION lock;                  // lock handle
    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&lock,0x00000400);
    EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
    #endif
    adr=(DWORD)(dat);
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        siz=sizes[i];                       // siz = actual block size
        num=(8<<20)/siz;                    // compute n (times to repeat the measurement)
        if (num<4) num=4;
        siz>>=2;                            // size / 4 because of 32bit transfer
        // measure overhead
        tbeg();                             // start time meassurement
        asm {
            push esi
            push edi
            push ecx
            push ebx
            push eax
            mov ebx,num
            mov al,0
    loop0:  mov esi,adr
            mov edi,adr
            mov ecx,siz
//          rep movsd                       // es,ds already set by C++
//          rep stosd                       // es already set by C++
            dec ebx
            jnz loop0
            pop eax
            pop ebx
            pop ecx
            pop edi
            pop esi
            }
        t0=tend();                          // stop time meassurement
        // measurement 1
        tbeg();                             // start time meassurement
        asm {
            push esi
            push edi
            push ecx
            push ebx
            push eax
            mov ebx,num
            mov al,0
    loop1:  mov esi,adr
            mov edi,adr
            mov ecx,siz
            rep movsd                       // es,ds already set by C++
//          rep stosd                       // es already set by C++
            dec ebx
            jnz loop1
            pop eax
            pop ebx
            pop ecx
            pop edi
            pop esi
            }
        t=tend();                           // stop time meassurement
        t-=t0; if (t<1e-6) t=1e-6;          // remove overhead and avoid division by zero
        t=double(siz<<2)*double(num)/t;     // Byte/ms
        pmovsd[i]=t/(1.024*1024.0);         // MByte/s
        // measurement 2
        tbeg();                             // start time meassurement
        asm {
            push esi
            push edi
            push ecx
            push ebx
            push eax
            mov ebx,num
            mov al,0
    loop2:  mov esi,adr
            mov edi,adr
            mov ecx,siz
//          rep movsd                       // es,ds already set by C++
            rep stosd                       // es already set by C++
            dec ebx
            jnz loop2
            pop eax
            pop ebx
            pop ecx
            pop edi
            pop esi
            }
        t=tend();                           // stop time meassurement
        t-=t0; if (t<1e-6) t=1e-6;          // remove overhead and avoid division by zero
        t=double(siz<<2)*double(num)/t;     // Byte/ms
        pstosd[i]=t/(1.024*1024.0);         // MByte/s
        }
    #ifdef measure_lock
    LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&lock);
    #endif
    #ifdef measure_priority
    hnd=GetCurrentProcess(); if (hnd!=NULL) { SetPriorityClass(hnd,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS); CloseHandle(hnd); }
    #endif
    delete dat;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where arrays `pmovsd[]` and `pstosd[]` holds the measured `32bit` transfer rates `[MByte/sec]`. You can configure the code by use/rem two defines at the start of measure function.

**Graphical Output:**

[image: memory benchmark measured data]

To maximize accuracy you can change **process priority class** to maximum. So create measure thread with max priority (I try it but it mess thing up actually) and add **critical section** to it so the test will not be uninterrupted by **OS** as often (no visible difference with and without threads). If you want to use `Byte` transfers then take account that it uses only `16bit` registers so you need to add loop and address iterations.

**PS.**

If you try this on notebook then you should overheat the **CPU** to be sure that you measure on top **CPU/Mem** speed. So no `Sleep`s. Some stupid loops before measurement will do it but they should run at least few seconds. Also you can synchronize this by **CPU** frequency measurement and loop while is rising. Stop after it saturates ...

**asm** instruction `RDTSC` is best for this (but beware its meaning has slightly changed with new architectures).

If you are not under **Windows** then change functions `tbeg,tend` to your **OS** equivalents

**[edit2] further improvements of accuracy**

Well after finally solving problem with **VCL** affecting measurement accuracy which I discover thanks to this question and more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21516244/2521214), to improve accuracy you can prior to benchmark do this:

1. **set process priority class to `realtime`**
2. **set process affinity to single CPU**

   so you measure just single **CPU** on multi-core
3. **flush DATA and Instruction CACHEs**

For example:

```
    // before mem benchmark
    DWORD process_affinity_mask=0;
    DWORD system_affinity_mask =0;
    HANDLE hnd=GetCurrentProcess();
    if (hnd!=NULL)
        {
        // priority
        SetPriorityClass(hnd,REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
        // affinity
        GetProcessAffinityMask(hnd,&process_affinity_mask,&system_affinity_mask);
        process_affinity_mask=1;
        SetProcessAffinityMask(hnd,process_affinity_mask);
        GetProcessAffinityMask(hnd,&process_affinity_mask,&system_affinity_mask);
        }
    // flush CACHEs
    for (DWORD i=0;i<sizes[N-1];i+=7)
        {
        dat[i]+=i;
        dat[i]*=i;
        dat[i]&=i;
        }

    // after mem benchmark
    if (hnd!=NULL)
        {
        SetPriorityClass(hnd,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
        SetProcessAffinityMask(hnd,system_affinity_mask);
        }
```

So the more accurate measurement looks like this:

[image: more accurate output]

Comment: A critical section doesn't mean your user-space code runs with interrupts disabled.  It only means that no other thread can enter the critical section.  IDK if the Windows kernel's scheduler gives any kind of priority boost to processes that are inside a critical section, but that effect would have to be limited or else any program could enter a critical section at startup and have higher priority than it was otherwise allowed to request for the whole time it was running.  I don't *think* Linux gives a prio boost specifically for futex.

Comment: You don't need to push/pop registers yourself in inline asm.  In MSVC-style the compiler parses your asm to see what it clobbers, and emits appropriate surrounding code.  Also, it's weird to use `rep movsd` with overlapping buffers.  I would have expected your src=dst case to be slow.

Comment: L1D is "a mess" because **your Bulldozer-family CPU has a write-through L1D cache with a 4kiB write-combining buffer**, so once your write-set is larger than 4k, you're mostly bottlenecked on L2 store bandwidth.  A cache *read* test (like reading a dword every 64 bytes) would have found the expected fall-off at around 16kiB, https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/9/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34143603/224132.  Ryzen is back to a normal write-back L1D design; Bulldozer L1D was a mistake.  (I can tell it's a Bulldozer-family from the 16k/4-way L1D, 64k/2-way L1I, and 2M L2.  Def. not Intel).

Comment: @PeterCordes your guess is right it was an AMD :) not sure which probably some x3 core at that time... btw it was not MSVC compiler but Borland instead which has diametraly different `asm {}` behavior especially in performance ... but the `push/pops` are to ease my mind mostly

Comment: @PeterCordes btw I recently ported this to measure HDD .... [HDD access + search time calculation algorithm based on read/write speed and HDD buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477032/2521214)

Answer (score 4):

Your `lengthMod` variable doesn't do what you think it does. You want it to limit the size of your data set, but you have 2 problems there -

- Doing a bitwise AND with a power of 2 would mask off all bits except the one that's on. If for e.g. `lengthMod` is 1k (0x400), then all indices lower than 0x400 (meaning i=1 to 63) would simply map to index 0, so you'll always hit the cache. That's probably why the results are so fast. Instead use `lengthMod - 1` to create a correct mask (0x400 --> 0x3ff, which would mask just the upper bits and leave the lower ones intact).
- Some of the values for `lengthMod` are not a power of 2, so doing the `lengthMod-1` isn't going to work there as some of the mask bits would still be zeros. Either remove them from the list, or use a modulo operation instead of `lengthMod-1` altogether. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136846/write-a-program-to-get-cpu-cache-sizes-and-levels/19142024#19142024) for a similar case.

Another issue is that 16B jumps are probably not enough to skip a cachline as most common CPUs work with 64 byte cachelines, so you get only one miss for every 4 iterations. Use `(i*64)` instead.