# Benchmarking affected by VCL

Tags: c++, c++builder, benchmarking, vcl, cpu-cache

Today I ported my old memory benchmark

from **Borland C++ builder 5.0** to **BDS2006 Turbo C++** and found out weird thing.

- exe from **BCB5** runs OK and stable
- exe from **BDS2006** measure OK only before main Form is started (inside its constructor) and if the benchmark is started again after main form is `Activated` or even after any **VCL** component change (for example `Caption` of main form) then the speed of benchmark thread is strongly affected.

[image: VCL memory benchmark]

After some research I found out that:

- Does not mater if test is inside thread or not.
- The process/thread priority,affinity does not affect this either.
- Hide of any window (`Visibility,Enabled`) does not affect this.
- call the test form `OnIdleEvent` does not affect this
- does not mater if time is measured by `RDTSC` or `PerformanceCounter`

My conclusion is that **VCL** library runs some code/thread on the background so my questions are:

1. **Is there a way to temporarily pause VCL code/stuff ?**

   ideal something like `Application->Pause();` and `Application->Resume();` or just `Forms`.
2. **what else could cause this behavior and how to avoid it ?**

**PS.**

Test application has no **VCL** components other than main form. Benchmark is just a few memory transfers by `rep stosd` with different block sizes (no funny stuff). Source is in [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214). I know **BDS2006** is out-dated but I am not looking for upgrade right now so please skip any comments about that they are not help-full at all.

Tested on **Windows7 pro x64**, `32bit` Application

Comment: You've got some debugging to do. I suggest you narrow things down a little before asking. And no, the VCL doesn't run extra threads just for kicks. If you want to see what threads are running then use one of the many debuggers that give you that info. Bottom line is that you need to gather more info and narrow this down.

Comment: @David Heffernan I spend quite a few hours before posting this question and eliminate almost everything (just WNDPROC remains) what could cause this in empty app with just single memtest function. After quite a few hours more I found out that wndproc in BDS2006::VCL invalidates/fills posibly instruction CACHE of CPU.

Comment: The thing is, all these are details of your application that we cannot really see or understand.

Comment: Yeh I know but in PS of question is stated that is a clean App (no additional VCL components besides form) and also what I had elliminated before ... but yes I could write it better thank for inside anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `wndproc` in **BDS2006::VCL** `invalidates` **CACHE**s.

1. **I have tried to override `wndproc` by `winapi`**

   for `Application->Handle` is this easy but it does not stop the processing of messages for `Form`. When I tried `Form1->Handle` as window then `error 1400` occurs (not valid window handle)
2. **I have tried to override `wndproc` by VCL**

   for Application by `TApplication events` and for `Form` by override of virtual `wndproc` member. Message processing stops but their calling sequences remains and the problem is not solved either.

So my conclusion after eliminating every possibility I can think off is that I need to flush **CACHE** more intensively somehow after setting process/thread for benchmarking.

In **DOS** I would done it by single instruction but on **windows** it is more tricky. Well The previous version of memory benchmark used just memory filling which is obviously not enough for **BDS2006** exe. I think that instruction **CACHE** is involved in this problem not data cache so I change it a bit and it finally worked thing out.

**Flushing the CPU CACHE:**

```
for (DWORD i=0;i<(128<<20);i+=7)
    {
    dat[i]+=i;
    dat[i]*=i;
    dat[i]&=i;
    }
```

Where dat is `128MB` allocated memory chunk (or bigger) and must be done after all process/thread priority and affinity changes or all **winapi** calls prior to benchmarking.