# Why does Math.abs take so much longer than Math.round?

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, profiling, profiler

I know Math.abs() and Math.round() are very different functions, but I assumed they would have a relatively similar efficiency.

```js
console.time('round');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

  var a = Math.random() - 0.5;
  Math.round(a);
}
console.timeEnd('round');
console.time('abs');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

  var a = Math.random() - 0.5;
  Math.abs(a);
}
console.timeEnd('abs');
```

The previous produced these results:
round: 136.435ms
abs: 4777.983ms

Can anyone explain the radical difference in the timing?

**EDIT:  When I run the snippit here i get MUCH faster results.  Around 2 and 3 ms.  Why on earth would it get such radically higher times in a different tab?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **I am not sure you are measuring what you think you are**

   The random can really mess things up by cache missing. Also you are substracting by `0.5` which is also **FPU** operation that is quite more complex then `abs` itself. I am not JAVA coder but I hope `Math.abs(x)` is floating point and not integer operation (In C/C++ `abs` is integer and `fabs` is floating point). I would create array with random numbers set prior to your loops and then use that in your loops
2. **`abs`**

   `abs` is just sign bit test + non zero mantissa test. if implementation contains brunch then that can seriously slow thing down. Luckily float/double abs implementation does not need any brunch you just mask out the sign bit (as mantissa is not in 2'os complement for standard IEEE 754 formats).
3. **`round`**

   `round` is test if MSB of fractional part of mantissa is 1 and if yes then is integer increment applied. so the target is bit shifted to integer and MSB fraction bit is extracted. if implementation contains brunch then that can seriously slow thing down but usually faster is extract the MSB fraction bit to Carry flag and use `adc`. Still this needs more work than `abs` and so it should be slower.
4. **so why the results are as are?**

   Is your implementation/platform using FPU or software emulation? On FPU the complexity of both operations is almost the same (because the overhead of communication with FPU is usually bigger then such operation itself). On emulation it depends on implementation of the operations and target platform architecture (pipelines,cache control,...)

   my guesses are:

   - `abs` loop is worse with Cache misses
   - `abs` implementation is not that much optimized as it could be
   - `round` is optimized by compiler, sometimes `round(x)=floor(a+0.5)` and you have `a-=0.5;` before and as you do not use `a` for anything else there is a possibility compiler ignores the `floor(random-0.5+0.5)` and use directly `floor(random)`

**[notes]**

The times you measured 132ms and 4.7sec are way too big on what HW did you try this? The times from your edit are much more reasonable for common PC HW and code interpreter these days. Did you measure this more then 1 times ?

If you are trying this in brownser then it could be slowed down by anything in its background (like snipped from different page or still downloading something ...) Also OS can pause the execution but not that much

Comment: Initially, I ran it in Chrome on my PC (not sure on specs, but its fairly powerful), since then, I am just getting the faster speeds.  I guess it must have been slowed down by something in the background.

Answer (score 1):

NOT AN ANSWER, but a bit research.

V8 engine source (https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git) I found following implementation in `src/math.js`

**Math.random**

```
function MathRound(x) {
  return %RoundNumber(TO_NUMBER_INLINE(x));
}
```

Where `%RoundNumber` should refer to `src/runtime/runtime-maths.cc`

```
RUNTIME_FUNCTION(Runtime_RoundNumber) {
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  DCHECK(args.length() == 1);
  CONVERT_NUMBER_ARG_HANDLE_CHECKED(input, 0);
  isolate->counters()->math_round()->Increment();

  if (!input->IsHeapNumber()) {
    DCHECK(input->IsSmi());
    return *input;
  }

  Handle<HeapNumber> number = Handle<HeapNumber>::cast(input);

  double value = number->value();
  int exponent = number->get_exponent();
  int sign = number->get_sign();

  if (exponent < -1) {
    // Number in range ]-0.5..0.5[. These always round to +/-zero.
    if (sign) return isolate->heap()->minus_zero_value();
    return Smi::FromInt(0);
  }

  // We compare with kSmiValueSize - 2 because (2^30 - 0.1) has exponent 29 and
  // should be rounded to 2^30, which is not smi (for 31-bit smis, similar
  // argument holds for 32-bit smis).
  if (!sign && exponent < kSmiValueSize - 2) {
    return Smi::FromInt(static_cast<int>(value + 0.5));
  }

  // If the magnitude is big enough, there's no place for fraction part. If we
  // try to add 0.5 to this number, 1.0 will be added instead.
  if (exponent >= 52) {
    return *number;
  }

  if (sign && value >= -0.5) return isolate->heap()->minus_zero_value();

  // Do not call NumberFromDouble() to avoid extra checks.
  return *isolate->factory()->NewNumber(Floor(value + 0.5));
}
```

**Math.abs**

```
function MathAbs(x) {
  x = +x;
  return (x > 0) ? x : 0 - x;
}
```

**Node.JS uses V8 enginge and so does Chrome**

My testcase:

```
var randoms = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    randoms.push(Math.random() - 0.5);
}

for(var r = 0; r < randoms.length; r++) {
    console.time('round');
    for (var i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++) {
        Math.round(randoms[i]);
    }
    console.timeEnd('round');

    console.time('abs');
        for (var i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++) {
        Math.abs(randoms[i]);
    }
    console.timeEnd('abs');  
}
```

Results:

- Chrome (42.0.2311.152 m) - Math.random is faster
- Node.JS (v0.10.29) - Math.abs is faster

**Thoughts**

By the V8 source, I would expect to be `Math.abs` to be faster and it is in Node.JS, but not in Chrome.

Ideas why?

Comment: have you tried to swap the abs and round loops to check if your measurement is not affected by CACHE ...? also increasing the N=100000 should be safer ...

Comment: @Spektre Swapped around and the results are the same for Node.JS and Chrome.

Comment: by same you mean same as measured before swap or there is no difference between different browsers now?

Comment: @Spektre Same as measured before swap. It would be nice of me to provide graphs and numbers...

Comment: that discard the possibility of measurement affected by differently set CACHE  state prior to measurement disadvantaging one of the loops. something like this [Benchmarking affected by VCL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21516244/2521214)

Comment: @tiblu, thanks for such a detailed response!  I think I have a better idea of how they work now.