# Debugging projects in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, debugging, c++builder, c++builder-6

First of all **I know that Borland C++ Builder 6 is legacy software and it's best to get rid of it and rewrite the whole code in a newer IDE.** That's a plan indeed but before I do that I would like to launch the programs that I knew worked before on another machine.

I copied the projects from an old computer to a new one ensuring that the paths to source files and libraries are set correctly.

**Problem**:
when I try to debug the program I get this pop-up error with no additional information:

> [Error: Unable to create process: The request is not supported.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onMey.png)

There are two ways I kind of managed to get it to work:

1. program1 launched with no error after a couple of tries (was recreated on the new machine by moving the files which was a relatively easy and fast process)
2. program2 was a new empty project and I copied each function and component within each of the forms and manually set each property so that they matched the original one. This one was also able to debug successfully.

I have another 30 programs like this so it would be awesome not to have to copy each function by hand but simply move the files to new projects as in program1.

Comment: It's not legacy. It's museum software. I haven't even heard about this for over 30 years and of course I don't remember anything about it. You can be sure it doesn't support any C++ standard. Even STL wasn't finalized back then

Comment: Borland C++ 6 was released in November 2002.  It's pretty ancient.  Probably has incorporated the parts of Stepanov's STL that were standardized into C++98 into its own standard C++ library.  (But, I'm not even sure if Borland C++ 6 was C++98 compliant.)

Comment: So 20 years. In the meantime the OS changed as well. Most computers were 32-bit back then, even servers didn't use 64-bit. Developer machines probably run Windows Me, a completely different platform than the Windows NT from which current versions evolved from. The debugger probably chokes on the OS. I don't remember how debugging worked on Windows NT (actually 2000) back then.

Comment: You probably want to test this in a VM containing an old version of MS Windows.

Comment: Very likely a 32 vs 64 bit thing.

Comment: @nicemike2 I don't recall there ever being a Borland C++ 6.  I think it stopped at like 5.5.  Or did you mean Borland C++ **Builder** 6 instead?  Two completely different products.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes you're right it's Borland C++ Builder 6

Comment: @nicemike2 BCB6 was really nasty one (the worst BCB ever it beaten also BCB4 in buggyness BCB5 was way more stable) especially if you run it on more recent machine and OS ... On some machines/OS combinations helps if you run IDE with CPU affinity set to single CPU but in case your program uses threads you have to set your program affinity back to full CPUs support see [SetProcessAffinityMask example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214) on how to do it for app ...  IDE can be set in BCB6 icon properties. Without knowing more about your project is hard to tell it might be x64 problem

Comment: beware newer IDEs like RAD changed the compilation process so you might need to redo the code architecture in order to work properly especially if you have MDI and or multi Form app with shared global variables now it behaves more like buggy GC/GCC for  MCUs instead of normal C/C++ code where shared variables are not always shared (but made multiple local ones) no matter what you do ignoring stuff like `volatile,static,extern` in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last year, when I started converting a C++ Builder 6 project to V11. I was using Win 10 and, once I got it going, it was a far better environment than in an XP VM.

To make things work, I had to run the IDE as administrator and, if I remember correctly, in compatibility mode for Windows XP. Otherwise, Windows refused to give it permission to debug - I had the same error as your.

Once those settings were set I could debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm definitely going the check it out as I'm currently working on an another part of the project. I'll keep you updated if it worked or not